# using internal ADC in spartan 3e 1600e fpga kit

Tags: vhdl, fpga, adc

i cant not use the ADC feature in the kit. what i did understand is that the ADC which is e LTC1407A-1 need 2 input clocks to work. one for sampling and one for receiving data from the ADC so how to do that. do i have to generate 2 clock from the fpga which is impossible or there is something that i am missing. and is there is a way to create vhdl code to make the fpga ADC?

Comment: See *Harnessing VLSI System Design with EDA Tools* by Kamat, Shinde, Gaikwad, Guihilot, 3.4 VHDL Implementation of the ECG Soft IP Core which uses an LTC1407. From the LTC1407A datasheet there's a sample CONV (a clock) and SCK for the SPI interface, which you could expect to operate from a CPU or via a state machine.

Comment: This is a question for [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do i have to generate 2 clock from the fpga

No. I only see one clock signal: SCK

> which is impossible

No, it is possible.

> is something that i am missing.

Yes: Either a [clock divider](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/444385/Frequency-Divider-with-VHDL), or a [Digital Clock Manager](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp462.pdf)

> Is there is a way to create vhdl code to make the fpga ADC?

Yes.